# WPF button not applying all properties on hover

Tags: c#, wpf, button, colors, border

I am designing a custom login window for some software I am working on and I've reached the point where I can work on the aesthetics of it all.

I have a fair bit of experience in C# and WPF but I still consider myself a novice when it comes to the technicality of using WPF and the "correct" ways of doing things.

I have the following code which is for a button I have modified to my liking:

```
<Button Content="Log In" FontSize="22" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="White" Cursor="Hand">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="#FF343434" BorderThickness="0">
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>

            <Setter Property="Background">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                        <LinearGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                            <TransformGroup>
                                <ScaleTransform CenterY="0.5" CenterX="0.5"/>
                                <SkewTransform CenterY="0.5" CenterX="0.5"/>
                                <RotateTransform Angle="-45" CenterY="0.5" CenterX="0.5"/>
                                <TranslateTransform/>
                            </TransformGroup>
                        </LinearGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF00A3E0" Offset="0"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFAB6BE3" Offset="1"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>

            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF00A3E0"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF343434"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="5"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>

    <Button.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Border">
            <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="10"/>
        </Style>
    </Button.Resources>
</Button>
```

As you can see, all I have is a gradient color by default which changes (at least it should) to a solid color with a border when the mouse is over it.

What I end up getting is only the background color change and nothing with the borders. I'm not sure if I have to write out a full control template to get this to work (I'd like to avoid it if possible) or if I've just been staring at it too long to see the obvious error.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Long story short, it turns out that for some reason I needed to name the border object in the template and apply the trigger in the template too to be able to specify that the `BorderBrush` and `BorderThickness` attributes had to be applied to said border.

Here is the final code:

```
<Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="9" Content="Log In" x:Name="log_in_button">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="#FF343434" BorderThickness="1" x:Name="log_in_button_border">
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF00A3E0"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF343434" TargetName="log_in_button_border"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2" TargetName="log_in_button_border"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
            <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="22"/>
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="/Password Manager;component/Resources/#Lato"/>
            <Setter Property="Background">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                        <LinearGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                            <TransformGroup>
                                <ScaleTransform CenterY="0.5" CenterX="0.5"/>
                                <SkewTransform CenterY="0.5" CenterX="0.5"/>
                                <RotateTransform Angle="-45" CenterY="0.5" CenterX="0.5"/>
                                <TranslateTransform/>
                            </TransformGroup>
                        </LinearGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF00A3E0" Offset="0"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFAB6BE3" Offset="1"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>

    <Button.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Border">
            <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="10"/>
        </Style>
    </Button.Resources>
</Button>
```

I am however, curious if anyone could give an explanation for this version to work and not the one I posted in the question (I like when things work but I like it more when I understand why).

Thanks!

Comment: You can check the default template of the button, that also has a border, and Border related properties a TemplateBound to that border.
You are redefining the whole template of the button, so it doesn't know what to do with the BorderThickness and BorderBrush properties in your first method.